# pavucontrol switch to HDMI if change media or pause

Tags: sound, 22.04, pavucontrol

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. When I use HDMI, some times I need to use headphones, for which to work I need to use `pavucontrol` and select *Audio Analog*.

The problem is that I need to select *Audio Analog* again if I change media or pause.

How can I select *Audio Analog* and keep it that way?

Note: `pavucontrol` shows headphones unplugged all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around, disable HDMI Audio output.

```
  $  pavucontrol
```

Configuration (last tap)

Built-in Audio (the one with HDMI output)

And set it from `(HDMI output)` to `Off`

later if you need you can reset HDMI Audio back.

[image]